# Python and memory consumption when opening TIFF images

Tags: python, opencv, tiff

I am writing a program that deals with several 16-bit TIFF images that consumes a lot of RAM.

If I am opening images like this:

```
import cv2
for i in range(1000):
    img = cv2.imread(file[i])
```

Does each image array go to memory, or does it get deleted when I assign it to the new value?
If it does not get deleted, how can I delete it before opening a new one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For each iteration, `img` gets reassigned, so the old frames will get deleted automatically by the garbage collector.

Comment: just make sure you don't have any other references to it floating around.

Answer (score 1):

If, for some reason the interpreter is not garbage collecting the data, you can force its hand with this:

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

Only do this if you know there's a memory leak, however, as running it (especially looping it!) can slow your program down, and it's usually best to leave memory management to the interpreter.

Comment: Thanks, I do it after the loop!

Comment: np! I'm curious to hear if it actually reduces memory use in this case