# OpenCV - clean memory

Tags: python, opencv, memory-leaks

is there a way to clean the memory occupied by `cv2.imread`? I wrote a script to load and analyse a stack of images and I am having some memory leak issues, I suspect because the images are kept in storage. What I am doing now is just

```
im = cv2.imread('file.tif')
[...]
del im
```

Which doesn't seem to work. Thanks!

Comment: Does [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/14285/how-to-free-memory-through-cvmat/) help?

Comment: @GPPK I'm looking exactely for something like that. But I haven't found any way to do it in Python... `im.release` does not work (`'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'release'`) and neither `cv2.release()` (`'module' object has no attribute 'release'`).

Comment: hi..this is a wild guess.but may be try `gc.collect()` after del?

Comment: Is it possible that the garbage collector has troubles dealing with objects imported using OpenCV? I added `gc.collect()` and `del gc.garbage[:]` at the end of the cycle, and I still have the leak.

Comment: these should be numpy arrays instead of opencv stuff

Comment: There is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414289/python-and-memory-consumption-when-opening-tiff-images) question on SO?

Comment: @ZawLin I agree, but if I remember correctly I had to use opencv to load a stack of images using somethign like `cv2.imread(file"%03i.tif" % (number),-1)`

Comment: ok now I put a number of `gc.collect()` in the code, but the memory consumption does not decrease

Comment: is that opencv3.0 ? they had a [memleak previously](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3470#note-6)

Comment: @berak bingo! I am using opencv 2.4.7.1, installed using homebrew. Where can I download the 3.0?

Comment: sorry for being misleading, but it was a 3.0 issue only, and got fixed last week. if you're using using opencv 2.4.7, that does not apply to you. but if you want 3.0, it's on [github](https://github.com/itseez/opencv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the code using [memory profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) and I located the leak, which had nothing to do with OpenCV. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I'm experiencing similar issue now. What what the cause in your case, if I might ask?

Comment: I don't remember, to be honest... it was a while ago and I never finished that project :/